# How to distribute a decimal by .5 as evenly as possible with no rounding

Tags: c#

I have an input number that is guaranteed to be specified as ***n***.0 or ***n***.5

Example inputs (only a single input is provided):

```
    0
    0.5
   13.0
   13.5
13337.5
28091.0
```

I need to distribute this number by ***n*** values so that all values total the input exactly, but all values must be ***n***.0 or ***n***.5 with NO rounding allowed.

For example, if 13.5 is input and needs to be distributed between 4, the resulting values would be:

```
3.5
3.5
3.5
3.0
```

Another example, if 1.0 is specified and needs to be distributed between 4, the resulting values would be:

```
0.5
0.5
0.0
0.0
```

I'm thinking the function signature would look similar to:

```
private List<decimal> DistributeEvenly(decimal amount, int numDistributions) 
{
    ...
}
```

I do find examples of how to distribute numbers evenly, but not with the ***n***.0 and ***n***.5 requirement and also not without rounding. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Yikes! I typo'd. You are right and the numDistributions was wrong too! Edited and corrected. Thx.

Comment: I would probably go with `List<float>` as you only need two decimal places

Comment: What if the amount is 2.7? Do you expect the last distribution to be n.2 or n.5? You say _"as evenly as possible"_

Comment: In the very first line I state that the input is guaranteed to be n.0 or n.5

Comment: Oh gotcha. Glossed over that. Thanks

Comment: The easiest way is use integers and then use 5 * ( x / 5).  Finally divide by 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just divide the input amount by the number of distributions, ignoring any remainder and use that as the base value.  Then take the remainder and subtract 0.5 for each distribution until it is gone.  Something like this:

```
private List<decimal> DistributeEvenly(decimal amount, int numDistributions)
{
    var result = new List<decimal>();

    //Determines the whole number part of each distribution
    decimal baseValue = (int)(amount / numDistributions);

    //Fill the list with the baseValue, numDistributions times
    result.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(baseValue, numDistributions));

    //The remainder will be distributed in amounts of 0.5 until it runs out
    decimal remainder = amount - (baseValue * numDistributions);

    int index = 0;

    while (remainder > 0)
    {
        result[index] += 0.5m;
        index++;
        if (index >= numDistributions)
        {
            index = 0;
        }

        remainder -= 0.5m;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: This is very close to working for me. More times than not it succeeds. But I've been trying to figure out how to fix it for `amount=9` and `numDistributions=5` (for example). Do you see why the code doesn't work with these inputs?

Comment: Another example of inputs that don't work is `amount=999.5` and `numDistributions=5`

Comment: See the update.  I wasn't sure what your output needed to be for 9 and 5.  This code produces 2, 2, 2, 1.5, 1.5

Answer (score 0):

If you find the total of the numbers you're given and divide by the number of outputs required, you get the mean that's needed. If you divide this mean value by one-half (equivalently: multiply it by 2), take the floor of the result, and then multiply the result of that by one-half, you get the smaller of the two distinct numbers that need to be in your output list. It is simple from there to work out how many of the output numbers need to be increased by one-half.

Comment: There is only a single (decimal) input amount provided along with the number of distributions needed (int). I'm still trying to wrap my head around your logic. :S

Answer (score 0):

Just multiply every number by two, and then distribute them evenly by increments of 1 in a for loop until your total is 0. Divide the result by 2. (Or just do it with floats, but you might get rounding errors)

Comment: There is only a single decimal amount provided as input. I think I'm seeing how your logic would work though.